# Selenium (Python) selecting an option within a nested multiselect optgroup

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, optgroup

I have a nested multiselect. How do I select an option in Selenium (using python)? This is what I'm trying...

```
filter_brands = Select( filter_panel.find_element_by_css_selector("select.form-control#filter-brands[name='filter_brands']") )
filter_brands.deselect_all()
filter_brands.select_by_value("ABC") #doesnt work!
```

I think I need to select the `optgroup#filter-brands-optgroup` but I can't do that using `Select` (`Select` must select a `select` element)

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try by selecting based on visible text,

```
filter_brands.select_by_visible_text("ABC")
```

Answer (score 0):

To *select* the *option* with text as **ABC** from the *optgroup* you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  filter_panel.find_element_by_css_selector("select.form-control#filter-brands[name='filter_brands']>optgroup#filter-brands-optgroup option[value='ABC']").click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  filter_panel.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='form-control' and @id='filter-brands'][@name='filter_brands']/optgroup[@id='filter-brands-optgroup']//option[@value='ABC']").click()
  ```